# Why are some resources failing to load on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, google-chrome

Stack Overflow gravatar images are broken image icons, and the Stack Overflow answer box does not have the toolbar.

Is it just me, or do other people see this also?
[image: broken weirdness]

Strangely enough Meta Stack Overflow edit boxes do have the tool bar, however the gravatar icon is still broken.

Is this heartbleed's fault?

For some reason this only happens when I am logged into Chrome on one of my email accounts.

If I am logged into chrome with my primary email address, everything works fine.

When I am logged in as the user that it breaks for I get this error in loading:

> quant.js   edge.quantserve.com  GET  (failed)  net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED  application/x-javasc

I think I just have some JS malware or something. Believe it or not the comments etc at least pointed me in the right direction. Now I will work on getting rid of that.

Showing Failed Resource Load for quantserver
[image: Showing the only failed resource is quantserver]

This url is broken when using chrome user1
[image: gravatar url and broken image from chrome user1]

The same URL works fine when using chrome user2
[image: the same url but the image is not broken for chrome user2]

Comment: Turn of compatibility mode, reenable Javascript (i.e. don't block SE's Javascript).

Comment: No, it's because of global warming.

Comment: I havent been ... this just started happening when I got back from lunch ... how do you turn off compatibility mode in chrome?

Comment: It's just you .

Comment: do you have a content filter on your (work?) network?

Comment: yeah but its just Sophos ... and it worked before lunch ...

Comment: hmmm weird in only happens when I am logged into my work email(in chrome) .... when Im logged into my normal email in chrome its seems to work fine ... weird

Comment: Can you press F12, go to Network tab, reload when it's broken and see what requests are failing?

Comment: yeah pretty sure I just have some malware on this google chrome users setup stuff (thanks for making the title clearer @Ermacool ... at the time I wrote the question I really didnt know what the issue was)

Comment: Oh, I see. I suspect you have browser extension/addon which is changing the protocol of all requests to https. And indeed, https://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js fails with error due to mismatch in their certificates.

Comment: Yes, but not on SE side, rather quantserve.com side. That said, this specific resource should not affect anything in the UI, sure no other resources are failing too?

Comment: OK updated question with lots of pictures ... Im pretty sure thats the only resource that fails ...

Comment: Really weird, but sounds like a problem on your end.

Comment: yeah I agree ... but it is strange ...