# JW Player doesn't load on Stack Snippets but it does on Plunker

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

After [posting a demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45865719/2813224) using JW Player, I get this error:

```
"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined",
"filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 25,
"colno": 15
```

Yet [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/IJ4RGq3tWxiiBnJXjcQF/) functions perfectly on a copy/paste. I believe `jwplayer` is fully defined in:

```
<script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.js"></script>
```

I read this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251168/why-are-some-resources-failing-to-load-on-stack-overflow) and it made very little sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JW Player's CDN only serves files via HTTP. Stack Overflow is served via HTTPS. At some point in recent history all of the major browser vendors [started blocking all HTTP requests from documents served over HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content). The only way to fix this issue is to request the script via HTTPS, which is only possible if the server supports HTTPS requests.

Unfortunately JW Player's CDN does not support HTTPS requests. My first response would be to look for a third-party CDN. Lo and behold, [JSDeliver serves JW Player via HTTPS](http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/jwplayer).

Now we've taken care of the insecure content problem, but JW Player does not work in a sandboxed iframe without the `allow-same-origin` flag set due to its dependence on `Document.cookie`.

This is demonstrated by the example below throwing this error:

> Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

```js
try { jwplayer('x').setup({}) } catch(e) { console.log(e.message) }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jwplayer/7.1.4/jwplayer.js" id="x"></script>
```

Unfortunately, enabling the [`allow-same-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) flag on the `iframe` element would effectively defeat the sandbox as it would allow scripts to disable the sandbox flag programmatically.

> **Note:**
>
> - When the embedded document has the same origin as the main page, it is strongly discouraged to use both allow-scripts and
>     allow-same-origin at the same time, as that allows the embedded
>     document to programmatically remove the sandbox attribute.
>      Although it is accepted, this case is no more secure than not using the sandbox attribute.
> - Sandboxing in general is only of minimal help if the attacker can arrange for the potentially hostile content to be displayed in the
>     user's browser outside a sandboxed iframe. It is recommended that such
>     content should be served from a separate dedicated domain, to limit
>     the potential damage.
> - The sandbox attribute is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.
>
> <sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox</sup>

Stack Overflow would have to move the iframe source to a different origin, but I'm sure that isn't as easy to do as it was to write just now.